# NHibernate: how to express a specific "group by" query with criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, group-by, nhibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

**Question:**

What are the criteria/projections that can generate a following query?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, 0, 1) FROM Person GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Name, 0, 1)
```

(Obviously this one is easier with `DISTINCT`, but I'll need counts later, when I fix this one).

---

**My approaches:**

My main problem here is with constants, because if I use

```
Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.SqlFunction(
   "SUBSTRING",
   NHibernateUtil.String,
   Projections.GroupProperty("Name"),
   Projections.Constant(0),
   Projections.Constant(1)
))
```

I get

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, 0, 1) FROM Person GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Name, , )
```

which is kind of obvious from NH [source code](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Criterion/SqlFunctionProjection.cs?revision=3701&view=markup), but useless.
And if I do

```
Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.SqlFunction(
   "SUBSTRING",
   NHibernateUtil.String,
   Projections.GroupProperty("Name"),
   Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.Constant(0)),
   Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.Constant(1))
))
```

then I get

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, @p0, @p1) FROM Person GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Name, ?, ?)
```

where question marks seem to be some unresolved parameters, but I have no idea why.

---

**More details:**

I just found

```
AbstractEntityJoinWalker.InitProjection(
    SqlString projectionString,
    SqlString whereString,
    SqlString orderByString,
    string /* WTF? */ groupByString,
    SqlString havingString,
    LockMode lockMode
)
```

The type of `groupByString` looks extremely suspicious.

Comment: Can you fill in the dots? It's not clear what you're doing with incomplete code.

Comment: Ok, filled in the dots (unfortunately I do not have the code in front of me right now, but I think this is a correct one).

Comment: There's a possible workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006721/1606945

Answer (score 0):

This should work (although you might want SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 1) but anyway):

```
Projections.SqlGroupProjection(
    "SUBSTRING(Name, 0, 1) as FirstChar",
    "SUBSTRING(Name, 0, 1)",
    new [] {"FirstChar"}, 
    new[] {NHibernateUtil.String}
)
```