# Incorrect Syntax near "?" : Nhibernate Generated Query

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I am getting problem while working with positional parameters in Nhbernate.

Criteria GroupProperty is emitting sql with both named and positional variables.

This statement:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MatchStageFrom))
                .SetProjection(Projections.GroupProperty(
                    Projections.SqlFunction("substring", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("LastName"), Projections.Constant(0), Projections.Constant(1))
                    )
                );
```

is producing this SQL:

```
SELECT substring(this_.LAST_NAME, @p0, @p1) as y0_ FROM MATCH_STAGING_FROM this_ GROUP BY substring(this_.LAST_NAME, ?, ?)
```

which causes SQL to error with:

```
Incorrect syntax near '?'.

could not execute query
[ SELECT substring(this_.LAST_NAME, @p0, @p1) as y0_ FROM MATCH_STAGING_FROM this_ GROUP BY substring(this_.LAST_NAME, ?, ?) ]
Positional parameters: #0>0 #1>1 #2>0 #3>1
[SQL: SELECT substring(this_.LAST_NAME, @p0, @p1) as y0_ FROM MATCH_STAGING_FROM this_ GROUP BY substring(this_.LAST_NAME, ?, ?)]
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: It's nice to know I'm not the only one who's experienced this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in NHibernate, but if you just want those results you can get the same result by using Projections.Distinct instead of Projections.GroupProperty, ie:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MatchStageFrom))
            .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(
                Projections.SqlFunction("substring", NHibernateUtil.String, 
                    Projections.Property("LastName"), 
                    Projections.Constant(0), 
                    Projections.Constant(1))
                )
            );
```

Alternatively if you're selecting more than just the first char of the name, then you could probably get it to work using a subselect

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with `Projections.SqlFunction("concat" ...)`.  In the end, I worked around it by using `Projections.SqlProjection(...)` instead.  I don't like this answer, since I think it's probably less portable, but it did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

There is a bug in NHibernate when using group by and SqlFunction parameters.
"If one applies `Projections.GroupProperty(customProjection)`, the parameters in the projection are sent only once (for the `SELECT` clause), while the parameters in the `GROUP BY` clause are positional and missing in the query..."
([see](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3131))

Ran into the same bug and solved it by adding Custom SQL Functions to NHibernate at Runtime,
([see](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/06/14/adding-custom-sql-functions-to-nhibernate-at-runtime.aspx))

The workaround moves constant parameters out of the Projections.SqlFunction call and into the definition of the custom function ("year_week").

Old failing:

```
Projections.GroupProperty(
   Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.AnsiString,
      Projections.SqlFunction("to_char", NHibernateUtil.AnsiChar,
         Projections.Property(() => myAlias.Date),
         Projections.Constant("IYYYIW") // Turns into "?" in group by
      )
   )
)
```

Work around:

```
Projections.GroupProperty(
   Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.AnsiString,
      Projections.SqlFunction("year_week", NHibernateUtil.AnsiChar,
         Projections.Property(() => myAlias.Date)
         // constant moved to function definition
      )
    )
)
```

Function "year_week" defined like this:

```
DialectExtensions.RegisterFunction(sessionFactory, "year_week", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.String, "TO_CHAR(?1,'IYYYIW')"));
```